# How does accessing an item in an array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So this might receive some flak. But I just came across this question and I would want to find the reason behind it.

So let's say we have an array like this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Now if we want to access the 4th element, we do:

```
arr[4] //returns 5
```

But so does this:
arr[1, "abc, "somerandom", "some more random string", 4]

It just looks like as long as the last element points to some index in `arr` it will return the item of that index. Can anyone explain the theory behind it? It's just observation but there has to be some reasoning behind it. I mean why not the first element in the second square bracket being treated as index.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(arr[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]);
console.log(arr[1, "safdasf", "some random string", "safas", 4]);
```

Comment: See the duplicate; try `console.log((1, "abc", "somerandom", "some more random string", 4));`...

Comment: Also: [MDN – Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator).

Comment: Out of curiosity I thought I would see what TS would say here -> `Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.` , and that makes total sense.  But then tried on an ESLint playground and it doesn't pick it up.